# Matching a regex urls.py string

Tags: python, regex, django, python-2.7, django-urls

I am currently building a Django application and I am trying to make a regex for the urls.py to accept a string that matches the following html

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/carrentals/rentvehicle/ABC123
```

I want to match ABC123 to be the parameter and I set the url patterns code to be this

```
url(r'^carrentals/rentvehicle/(?P<numberplate>^[\w]+$)/$', 'car_rental_rentout')
```

but its not matching the Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`carrentals` does not match `rentvehicle`. And `/` does not exists in the url, but in the pattern. (added `?` after `/` to make the trailing slash optional)

```
url(r'^carrentals/carrentals/(?P<numberplate>[\w]+)/?$', 'car_rental_rentout')
```

Beside that, `^`, `$` used multiple times.